# How to auto format the code before commit in IntelliJ?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, formatting

Whenever I commit and push my code to git, it shows most of the formatting changes in merge request. I am using intellij as code editor. 
Is there anyway to auto format the whole project before committing changes ? 
So at least my merge request should not have code formatting changes every time.

Answer (score 11):

Open Settings > Version Control > Commit
Select on the bottom right under "Before Commit" the Reformat code checkbox.
[image]

Comment: I'm on CLion Nova and I have the same options except instead of "Before Commit" it says "Commit Checks" and then it causes the reformat to happen AFTER the commit, and then stages a new change with the reformatted code. Is there any way to get it to happen before?

Answer (score 2):

Are you working with co-workers on the same project? If so, you will need to align your code formatting otherwise you will keep seeing these changes no matter what you do.

You can reformat your whole project as suggested by @Kootli and submit it as a single commit. This way all subsequent commits should not show the code formatting changes anymore.

Another tip: you can also install the [save actions plugin](https://github.com/dubreuia/intellij-plugin-save-actions) to auto format your code but only change the changes lines. So it will leave the untouched lines as is, even if it doesn't adhere to the current code formatting rules. This should make your commits more 'clean'.

Answer (score 1):

Please in "Project" view right click on the folder you want to reformat, choose "Reformat code" from the menu.